# Unknown event DropGesture

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to add an event for drag/drop and I still have this message :

`Could not resolve type with token 0100004d from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.DropGestureRecognizer' in assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')'`

I'm up to date with Nuget packages.

Is there an extension to add ?

Here is the code used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SafeMountain"
             x:Class="SafeMountain.MainPage"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:SafeMountain.UserControls"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout Margin="15,15,0,0" x:Name="slItems">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" Drop="DropGestureRecognizer_Drop"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label x:Name="lblLastPosCatch" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightGray" FontSize="Micro"/>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="slDeconnexion">
                        <Label x:Name="lblDeconnexionInfo" TextColor="Red" Text="Déconnecté du réseau cellulaire" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Which line of the code throw this error? You could download the source file from the link. It works well on my side. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithgestures-draganddropgesture/

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT This error occures on InitializeComponent on the ContentPage containing the drag/drop gesture.
I tried this example and it works fine for me too... I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Could you provide  a code snippet for me to reproduce?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I've juste added it. I don't think the code is involved. Its maybe my projet configuration.

Comment: Glad that you have solved this issue.

Comment: @WENDYZANG-MSFT I didn't resolved it yet...

Comment: It works well on my side. Could provide more details so that i could give some suggestions?

Comment: I don't what else I can provide you. What do you need?

Comment: A code sample which could reproduce. You could upload on GitHub.